# Read numbers from a file and return sum of all the numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get sum of all the numbers which are separated by commas in a python file suppose (example.txt): which contain the numbers like,

```
2,3,5,6,9
1,5,6,9,4,5
9,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of reading files in python is to use `open()` and then either `read()` or `readlines()`. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python).

To get the numbers out, you need to split the read lines by the separator and convert them into an `int`.

Finally `sum()` will sum up all elements in a list.

```
#create an empty list to put numbers in
a = []

#open file and read the lines
with open("SO_sumofnumers.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    #split each line by the separator (",")
    l = line.split(",")
    for entry in l:
        # append each entry
        # removing line-end ("\n") where necessary
        a.append(int(entry.split("\n")[0]))

print a
#sum the elements of a list
s = sum(a)
print s
```